# I have to compress responseStream but stream is not writable.I have written this code but its not working(GZip Compression in C#)

Tags: c#, gzip

```
try
{
   TextReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
   gzipBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(reader.ToString());

   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
   // Use the newly created memory stream for the compressed data.
   outStream = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, true);
   outStream.Write(gzipBytes, 0, gzipBytes.Length);
   // Close the stream.
 }
 catch
 {
 }
```

Comment: There is no indication that you try to write to the responseStream. And you did not provide any error message either. I don't think that somebody will be able to help you that way. Please edit your post to enable people to help you with your problem.

Comment: `ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(reader.ToString())` is pretty much guaranteed not to work. Use `reader.readToEnd()` instead.

Comment: When responseStream put into the new GZipStream(responseStream , CompressionMode.Compress, true);then it throws exception "stream is not writable" to avoid this exception I have read responseStream in TextReader but its not work neither throw any exception.

Comment: Where is `responseStream` defined?

Comment: in response stream em getting the response  responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

Comment: `GetResponseStream` sounds like it's a response from a website. You can't write to a *website response*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, see if it doesn't work for you:

```
using (Stream inputStream = ...)
using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream())
using (GZipStream zipStream = new GZipStream(outputStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
{
    inputStream.CopyTo(zipStream);
}
```

all you would have to do is replace the first line `Stream inputStream = ...` with whatever your input stream is, so for example: `Stream inputStream = File.OpenRead(...)` or `Stream inputStream = new StreamReader(...)` ... whatever. Should copy to the `zipStream` and perform the compression.

Also, `using` blocks are good. They free up unmanaged resources rather than letting them float around until the garbage collector picks them up.